# Parse error: Invalid numeric literal after upgrade to laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, php-7

I am just upgrading laravel 5.1 to 5.2. Everything run smoothly except my seeder.

When I run seeder, i found this error:

```
admin@arrasyid:/var/www/sys_pb$ php artisan db:seed


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]  
  Parse error: Invalid numeric literal
```

I could not find the solution after googling on the error. Please give me an advice related to this. thanks

Comment: have you try `composer dump-autoload` ?

Comment: Can you provide the full exception back trace along with the relevant code that caused it, please?

Comment: @Follio, I've tried that too. but no luck

Comment: @Sherif, that's the exception that laravel gave when facing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ### From the PHP 7 Migration Guide in the Manual
>
> #### Invalid Octal Literals
>
> Previously, octal literals that contained invalid numbers were silently truncated (`0128` was taken as `012`). Now, an invalid octal literal will cause a *parse error*.
>
> [Changes to integer handling](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.integers)

So this means that something like this in your code as of PHP 7 can cause a fatal parse error with `Invalid numeric literal` whereas previously in PHP 5 it would have been silently ignored.

```
$arr = [08, 09, 10, 11]; // works in PHP 5, throws fatal error in PHP 7
```

See [this 3v4l](https://3v4l.org/lDOhs) as an example.

Comment: I've tried to comments all functions that related to data seeder. but it still fails with the same error. how do I solve the problem? does it related to the symfony?

Comment: If it's a `Throwable` type, chances are, it's coming from PHP. This specific exception in PHP 7, is about using numeric literals in your php code that aren't valid. See example in answer.

Comment: this solution is good for the project that just kicked out, in other words, when the project has small that's fine to change it. but when the source code complex, it could take much time to maintains or at least check it one by one.

Comment: @indi60 which part of this answer fixed your error because you accepted it? I am experiencing the exactly same error and have no clue how this solves the problem.. also I didn't upgrade my PHP version (I am using 7 but it has worked before).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error "Parse error: Invalid numeric literal". And for me it works just put single quotes in the numbers.
Like this:
$arr = ['08', '09', '10', '11']